# NetBeans syntax highlighting without php tags

Tags: php, netbeans

Does anyone know of a way to make NetBeans keep php syntax highlighting for php files even without the  tags?

I know, normally, you would not want this, as then it would apply PHP highlighting to HTML, however, the code base I work with is all PHP CLI, and uses only a shebang, not the tags.

Basically, I want NetBeans to still highlight php code that looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/php -F

echo "Hello World!\n";
```

instead of code that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

 echo "Hello World\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add "<?php" after comment like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -F
#<?php

echo "Hello World!\n";
```

This not will affect the run in php-cli and works well in Netbeans